# What is the Maximum number of valid Oauth2 JWT tokens that can exist at any given point in time?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics

Is there any limit to the maximum number of valid tokens that can exist at any given point in time?
For example, I understand that I can have 2 valid tokens at any given point in time.(Ive tested/valided this) But wondering what the logical limit is. Can I have 1 million valid tokens?
I am hesitant to test this constraint in order to validate, and hoping there is some documented limit somewhere if a limit exists.

Details:(for what it is worth)
Using Azure AD authentication , against Dynamics web API.

Comment: I'm curious why are you asking? A token is usually valid for one hour so you can cache them :)

Comment: Im asking because I want to understand the answer. Its a specific question and I want to avoid taking it off topic.

Comment: Right. I don't have an answer to your exact question. Though I think you can have quite a massive amount of tokens. The only issue would probably be the rate limit of the token endpoint. The tokens themselves are not stored in Azure AD, APIs verify them by checking the digital signature.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no maximum for number of tokens issued (you can check the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)) because in essence a token is just used to validate a claim verifying its signature with a private key. As commented above, the issuer is not required to store or keep track of tokens.

In practice though, you are limited by the performance of the network and your IP might be flagged and perhaps blocked by firewalls or other network protection agents, as asking repeatedly for tokens could be considered a DoS attack.

Comment: Thank you for this. I appreciate it.